# How to auto jump from div to div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a website for my university. My advisor requires features that will focus on selected divs on page load. That means when the full page will be loaded, there will be a pop up which will ask for a tour guide permission. If the permission is given, it will jump from one div to another till the end of the page. Can anyone help with any procedures?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

JS:

```
function jumpTo(id){
    window.location.hash = id;
}

function jumpToAll(){
    var ids = ["div1", "div2", "div3"];
    var n = 0;
    var intv = setInterval(function(){
        jumpTo(ids[n]);
        n++;
        if(n == ids.length){
            clearInterval(intv);
        }
    },5000)
}
```

Comment: thanks
it worked can you help me with another task please?
on each jump i want to auto hover over some elements..